# Ionic cloud build failed

Tags: angularjs, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I tried following other solutions but none of them are working.

Initially I tried using following commands.

```
cordova telemetry on
cordova telemetry off
cordova build --no-telemetry
```

but they didn't work either.

below is the output that I got from ionic server after the failure.

```
You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavacNote: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl
:compileDebugRenderscript
:generateDebugBuildConfig
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets
:generateDebugResValues
:generateDebugResources
:mergeDebugResources
AAPT: libpng error: Read Error
:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.75 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/package/workspace/apps-97d1fa95-3/cordova/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/package/workspace/apps-97d1fa95-3/cordova/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Note: I have also renamed this image file in www/img folder as suggested in other answers but that didn't worked either.

Comment: I am not sure, you can check by ionic  instead of cordova.

`ionic telemetry on` 
`ionic telemetry off` 
`ionic build --no-telemetry`

Comment: @AnowarHossainJeebon I tried that as well but no luck.